# How to set a rule that's too deep for UpValue?

Tags: pattern-matching, upvalues

I want to automatically transform `Conjugate[a CenterDot[x, y, z]]` to `Conjugate[a] Conjugate[CenterDot[x, y, z]]`. However, the following rule doesn't work:

```
CenterDot /: Conjugate[coeff_ CenterDot[content___]] := Conjugate[coeff] Conjugate[CenterDot[content]]
```

and the error message is `TagSetDelayed::tagpos: Tag CenterDot in Conjugate[CenterDot[content___] coeff_] is too deep for an assigned rule to be found.`

How to achieve my original transformation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a complete hack, but maybe you could try:

```
Clear[CenterDot]
CenterDot /: a_ b_CenterDot := Module[{stack=Stack[_]},
    foo[a, b] /; MatchQ[stack, {___, HoldForm[_Conjugate], _, _}]
]

foo /: Conjugate[foo[a_, b_]] := Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b]
```

Example:

```
Conjugate[x CenterDot[a, b, c] z + 3]
```

> 3 + Conjugate[x z] Conjugate[CenterDot[a, b, c]]

Answer (score 4):

Times is not too deep.

```
Unprotect[Times];
Times /: Conjugate[coeff_ CenterDot[content___]] := 
 Conjugate[coeff] Conjugate[CenterDot[content]]
```

Comment: You need to `Unprotect[Times];` for this to work.

Comment: I was looking for a resolution that doesn't require hacking internal symbols.